# Finitely many intersections between a smooth curve and the boundary of a ball

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

In proving one result in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, I need the following lemma:

Let $p$ be a point in a open ball $B$ and let $q$ be a point outside of the closed ball $\overline{B}$. For any smooth curve $\gamma: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ connecting $p$ and $q$, there exists at least one and also only finitely many intersections between $\gamma([a,b])$ and $\partial B$.

Is this lemma true? This looks intuitively correct, nevertheless, how can one rigorously prove this?

Comment: what if the curve has part of the circle (hole arc) ? So the Lemma is not true.

Comment: You need to choose the radius of the ball to be generic.

Comment: @dmtri I see, Thank you.